# Can I use an image to mark a point in a Matplotlib plot and how?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I would like to mark a few points in a 3D scatter plot in Python + Matplotlib using a small symbol image instead of Matplotlib's standard marker signatures. Alternatively, I could do with using a unicode glyph instead of an image if this is easier.
Is this possible and how?

Comment: I guess you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180327/matplotlib-3d-scatter-plot-with-images-as-annotations)?

Comment: Oh yes, that could look like it does the trick. I'll try.