# Affinity Propagation for Image Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, unsupervised-learning

The link [here](https://techblog.gumgum.com/articles/k-means-clustering-of-sports-images) describes a method for image classification using affinity propagation. I'm confused as to how they got the feature vectors, i.e, the data structure of the images, e.g, arrays?

Additionally, how would I accomplish this given that I can't use Places365 as it's custom data (audio spectrograms)?

Finally, how would I plot the images as they've done in the diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are passed through a neural network. The activations of neural network layer for an image is the feature vector. See https://keras.io/applications/ for examples.

Spectrograms can be treated like images.

Sometimes even when domain is very different, the neural network features can extract useful information that can help you with clustering/classification tasks.

Comment: How did they plot the images, and what neural network should I choose? I'm really new to unsupervised learning.

Comment: It is a scatterplot with images as annotations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180327/matplotlib-3d-scatter-plot-with-images-as-annotations

Comment: You can use any well-known neural network. VGG16 or Inception trained on Imagenet may work for your use case

Comment: is there a reason why they used a 365 dimensional vector?

Comment: Because they are using last layer of the network trained for Places 365 dataset. Last layer has 365 outputs leading to a 365-d vector.

Comment: Ah ok. That's really self explanatory. So then, just to clarify, the feature vector is done through using a neural net to predict, i.e, vgg16's predict function?

Comment: Is there a way for me to get the corresponding image to the corresponding point or cluster for image annotations? So far I've only found that they've just used a labeled image as a representation for the point, not the image that belongs to the point.